# Не получается подключится к серверу через mosh

Tags: сервер, debian, ssh, yandex-cloud, яндекс-облако

Поднял сервер на `Debian` установил `SSH-ключ`. По команде:

```
ssh -i yandex_key em0ji@51.250.23.237
```

подключаюсь к серверу:

```
Linux rowihost 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Mon Nov  8 10:16:07 2021 from 31.181.190.176
```

Проблем никаких нет, полет нормальный, но как только пытаюсь подключиться через `mosh`:

```
mosh em0ji@51.250.23.237
```

В терминале падает ошибка:

```
em0ji@51.250.23.237: Permission denied (publickey).
/usr/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message. (Have you installed mosh on your server?)
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: «Have you installed mosh on your server?» — перевод: «mosh установлен на вашем сервере?»

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в том то и дело, что установлен

Comment: значит, смотрите логи.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а какие конкретно логи надо посмотреть? Я вот перешел в `/var/log/` и там нет папки с `mosh`.

Comment: логи, создаваемые программой mosh-server. где сконфигурировано у вас в системе их сохранять — не имею понятия. см. man-страницу, конф.файлы, входящие в пакет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, всего-навсего надо было добавить `ssh-ключ` в `ssh-agent`. Итак, сначала проверяем доступность `ssh-agent` командой:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Вывод терминала:

```
Agent pid 2985
```

Затем проверяем, что у нас есть сгенерированный и загруженный в `SSH` приватный ключ:

```
ssh-add -l
```

У меня терминал выдал такой ответ:

```
The agent has no identities.
```

После этого надо просто скопировать приватный ключ в `~/.ssh` и ввести команду:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/name_key
```

И получить ответ:

```
Identity added: /home/kali/.ssh/name_key (user@group)
```

После таких манипуляций можно входить на сервер по сокращенной команде `ssh username@IP_server` или `mosh username@IP_server`

Ну и не забываем добавить `ssh-agent` в автозагрузку.