# Как вернуть возможность подключаться по ssh из Windows10 к Ubuntu(который установлен на virtualBox)?

Tags: ssh, администрирование, ssh-key, openssh

Подключалась раньше по ssh и из WinSCP и из cmd
с помощью команды ssh userName@192.168.x.x

После того, как в линуксе создала ssh-ключи (ssh-keygen) пропала возможность подключаться по ssh.

Потом, кажется полностью, удалила с помощью команды rm -f .ssh/known_hosts эти ключи, но доступ по ssh так и не возобновился.

Comment: если вы удалили `known_hosts` то как собрались подключаться к серверу по `ssh`?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать команду `ssh -i private_server_key username@192.168.x.x` , где `private_server_key` это приватный ключ от сервера. Перейдите в директорию нахождения приватного ключа и выполните команду выше.

Comment: em0ji ваш ответ является правильным. Вы меня спасли от переустановки линукса. Либо от недели мучительных исканий в чем причина. Если вы пропишете вашу команду ответом, я выберу ваш ответ лучшим ответом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать команду:

```
ssh -i private_server_key username@192.168.x.x
```

где `private_server_key` это приватный ключ от сервера, а `username@192.168.x.x` - ваш сервер. Перейдите в директорию нахождения приватного ключа и выполните команду выше.

А ещё я советую посмотреть здесь [Не получается подключится к серверу через mosh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347267/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-mosh) как настроить вход на сервер по упрощенной команде `ssh username@192.168.x.x`.